# Numerically sorting the String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, java-8

I already know that we can sort string arrays numerically, by converting them to integer array then using `Arrays.sort()` or using any comparator.

So my question is if those strings are beyond the limit of integer or long int then how can we sort them. For example consider the following string array:

```
14829435897932384626433832795
4159265358979323846264338327
1937286535897932384626433832795296523
23746289
```

in those cases traditional comparator or any sorting method won't work because in turn they use integer (or any other datatype).

Comment: Convert them to BigInteger

Comment: Option 1: BigInteger
Option 2: compare by length first, if that is equal, compare as String

Comment: `BigInteger` seems a better option specifically for cases where the `String` can start with a bunch of zeros, e.g. `000133124953`. Length comparison would be problematic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare big integers in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543987/compare-big-integers-in-array)

Comment: yes biginteger seems better . Thanks @Eran , @ GaborSch , @ Everyone

Comment: I would prefer option 2 (compare string length then compare as String) with a comparator that skips any leading zeros. It would probably be more efficient as you won't be creating new objects and allocating arrays to hold the BigInteger values. If readability is the only requirement, then use BigInteger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.sort(array, comparator)`

```
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::new));
```

- The `comparator` can take as [`parameter` a function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) that `maps` an object into another one (here [`String into BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-))

With details (from shorter to longer, Intellij will propose you to use 1st one) :  :

```
= Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::new)
= Comparator.comparing(val -> new BigInteger(val))
= Comparator.comparing((o1, o2) -> new BigInteger(o1).compareTo(new BigInteger(o2)))
```

---

```
String[] array = new String[]{"14829435897932384626433832795", 
                              "4159265358979323846264338327", 
                              "1937286535897932384626433832795296523", "23746289"};
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::new));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

//Will result in 
[23746289, 4159265358979323846264338327, 14829435897932384626433832795, 1937286535897932384626433832795296523]
```

Comment: Its a great solution definately , but there are some efficiency issue with it .

Comment: @SandipKumar details ?^^ You have a lot of String to convert and sort ?

Comment: yep , the one which i have given  are just sample ones , actual ones are way too larger .

Answer (score 9):

As suggested by Eran: Convert to `BigInteger` and do the comparison:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(o1);
        BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(o2);
        return bi1.compareTo(bi2);
    }
});
```

---

And because @tobias_k doesn't care about karma:

If you're running Java 8, you can use the many new default methods of the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface to do it in one line:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::new))
```

---

Just added a counter to the `Comparator` to see how many times a `String` was converted to a `BigInteger`. It counted 10 conversions in my simple run of 4 strings.

This made me think that there might be a performance gain by converting each string once, sorting the `BigInteger` instances and converting them back. Something like this:

```
List<BigInteger> list1 = list.stream().map(BigInteger::new)
     .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Java 8: `Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::new))`

Comment: @tobias_k: Nice! You should add that as answer.

Comment: Meh, it's basically the same. Feel free to add it to yours if you like.

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a custom comparator:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("14829435897932384626433832795", "4159265358979323846264338327", "1937286535897932384626433832795296523", "23746289", "4159265358979323846264338326");

// comparing by String if the length is equal
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo));

System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

> [23746289, 4159265358979323846264338326, 4159265358979323846264338327,
>   14829435897932384626433832795, 1937286535897932384626433832795296523]

Comment: As noted above, it works only if there are no leading zeros. But it we can assume it, this is the most effective. +1

Comment: `Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo));`

Comment: This was the exact solution i was looking for , it is correct as well as efficient , thanks .